# Writing over .html() with certain conditionals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display different strings depending on the score upon completion of a 10 question quiz but the strings are not showing up.  I'm not sure where I've gone wrong with the code:

The part of the code that add the strings is:

```
$('.continue').on('click', function() {
    populateQuestion(++currentQuestion);
  $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
  if(currentQuestion === 10  && correctAnswers === 10){
    $('.jumbotron').html('You got all 10 questions right!  Way to go SUPER NERD!');
  } else if(currentQuestion === 10  && correctAnswers >= 7){
    $('.jumbotron').html('You got ' +correctAnswers+ " questions right! Don't get caught riding nerdy!");
  } else if(currentQuestion === 10  && correctAnswers >= 5 ){
    $('.jumbotron').html(correctAnswers + ' questions right? You could use a little more nerd in your life.');
  } else if(currentQuestion === 10  && correctAnswers >= 3){
    $('.jumbotron').html(correctAnswers + '? Wow, what\'s up preppy?');
  } else if(currentQuestion === 10  && correctAnswers < 3){
    $('.jumbotron').html(correctAnswers + ' for real? At least you got your name right....I hope');
  }
  });
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class='jumbotron'>
    <h2 class='jumotron'></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="continue">
    <button class="click">Click here to continue<br><br>...if you dare!</button>
  </div>
```

The full code is on my jsfiddle at https://goo.gl/ZPIJvS

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: The strings I'm adding aren't showing up at all,

Comment: Now add what part is supposed to be showing the strings and it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it worked out.  I created a function to check the user's score, and print that corresponding string.

```
   function quizComplete(number){
  if(correctAnswers === 10){
    $('.jumbotron').html('You got all 10 questions right!  Way to go SUPER NERD!');
  } else if(correctAnswers >= 7){
    $('.jumbotron').html('You got ' +correctAnswers+ " questions right! Don't get caught riding nerdy!");
  } else if(correctAnswers >= 5 ){
    $('.jumbotron').html(correctAnswers + ' questions right? You could use a little more nerd in your life.');
  } else if(correctAnswers >= 3){
    $('.jumbotron').html(correctAnswers + '? Wow, what\'s up preppy?');
  } else if(correctAnswers < 3){
    $('.jumbotron').html(correctAnswers + ' for real? At least you got your name right....I hope');
  }
}
```

Then added that to the function that populates the quiz.

```
    function populateQuestion(index) {
    if (currentQuestion <=9){
    $('.q_question').html(questionsArray[index]['question']);
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        $('.jumbotron').html('');
        $('.btn' + (i + 1)).val(questionsArray[index]['choices'][i]).prop('checked', false);
      $('.label' + (i + 1)).html(questionsArray[index]['choices'][i]);
    }
  } else{ quizComplete(correctAnswers)}
}
```